# Do we have linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]
does that correct let v=(3,1,5) and u1=(1,0,0),and u2=(2,1,0) and we can see that u1+u2=3
u2=1 
my teacher said we have do it by showing one col of A is not a linear combination of basis for col(A)

Answer (score 1):

Try $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$. This should be easier to use.

---

For the two matrices $A$ and $B$ that you wrote, since you performed only elementary row operations on $A$ to get $B$, we do have $\text{row}(A) = \text{row}(B)$ as the problem requires.

However, you can check that $\text{col}(A) = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\text{col}(B) = \mathbb{R}^3$. So, $\text{col}(A) = \text{col}(B)$.

Therefore, you need to come up with a different example of $3 \times 4$ matrices $A$ and $B$.

---

Note: The above was answering the OP's original question before the OP edited it.

Now that you have edited the matrix $A$, your reasoning is correct. Note that every column of $B$ has a $0$ as its third component. So, any vector whose third component is non-zero cannot be written as a linear combination of the columns of $B$. This includes the third column of $A$, $v = (3,1,5)^T$.

Comment: we have to do it by R-E form :( ,and does that correct let v=(3,1,5) and u1=(1,0,0),and u2=(2,1,0) and we can see that u1+u2=3 u2=1 then i said since 0=5 that not correct so we do not have linear combination?

Comment: Where are you getting $v = (3,1,5)$ from?

Comment: my teacher said we have do it by showing one col of A is not a linear combination of basis for col(A)so i choose one col of A that (3,1,5) and the basis of (B)={(1,0,0) ,(2,1,0)}

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is a row reduced form of the matrix $A$, then there exists an invertible matrix $F$ such that $A=FB$. This is a fundamental tool in applications of Gauss' elimination other than solving linear systems, for example full rank decompositions and the computation of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

It's not difficult to show that, in general, if $A=FB$ with $F$ invertible, then the row spaces of $A$ and $B$ are equal, because the rows of $A$ are linear combinations of the rows of $B$ and, conversely, the rows of $B$ are linear combinations of the rows of $A$, using $B=F^{-1}A$.

On the other hand, if $A$ has rank at least $1$, the vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
belongs to the column space of the row reduced form $B$ of $A$, by construction.

So, for your exercise, take $A\ne0$ such that the vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
doesn't belong to the column space of $A$.